# Android - How to add an elem to a list via UI?

Tags: android, list

I searched many time but I don't have found any answers...
I would like make a dynamic list. If I press a button and I write anything, how I can stock in the list? What is the function to make that?

Thank all..

Comment: Please add some code...what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

attach the list to an adapter and add elements to the adapter through `add` method, the list will get updated once you call the `invalidate` method

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: `invalidate()` calls `onDraw()`, which only refreshes the graphical UI, not the data.

Comment: Ok it's good :) thank for your help :)

listElems.add(elemText.getText().toString());
                    elemText.setText("");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);